# How to avoid comma in comma delimited CSV with using XSLT

Tags: xslt, csv

Im using xslt for csv files. Sometimes there is a text like "a, b" in xml. When you choose comma delimited in excel for showing csv file, excel thinks that they have  to separated to columns. But I want to do just for column. Is there a way to do that in xslt part?

Answer (score 0):

In order to preserve spaces you need to quote values which contain commas. It is possible in XSLT, but the answer depends on your stylesheet design. If you want a more accurate answer, please share your code. Generally, you can use the following template to wrap any text nodes of interest in quotes:

```
<xsl:template match="text()[contains(., ', ')]">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;', ., '&quot;')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get clues from the open-source CSV to XML package in XSLT 2.0 I've published in the "Free Developer" section of my web site: http://www.CraneSoftwrights.com/resources/#csv it follows RFC4180 http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt

The idea is to look for quotes first and then commas when there aren't quotes.  This can be expressed in regex as I have done in the code I've cited.